# Addressing of COM Ports on Ubuntu don't match labels

Tags: serial-port

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS.
It's a small industrial PC with 6 Com ports.

I have plugged my device into what is labelled on the outside of the case as COM1
But through investigation I found that Ubuntu is addressing it as COM4

When I do `setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0-6]`

I get the following:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 7
/dev/ttyS3, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 7
/dev/ttyS4, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e0, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS5, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f0, IRQ: 7
/dev/ttyS6, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e0, IRQ: 7
```

My COM1 device is actually:

> /dev/ttyS4, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e0, IRQ: 4

How do I change the addresses to match the port labels on the front of the case?
Thank you in advance for all your assistance.

Comment: See if this helps https://serverfault.com/a/137595/363611

Comment: Not really, I cannot really do links as I need to reorder 1 to 4 and say 4 to 2 etc.

Comment: It makes nonsense. Labeling on the case is hard to follow because in every modern OS enumeration of the ports is flexible. With UARTs renumeration is a hard task to achieve due to legacy stuff that 8250 driver supports in the Linux kernel. In your case first 4 ports have standard (legacy) addresses, that's why enumeration looks like this. Best, what you may try to do is to get your ports non-standard (legacy) addresses by configuring on the hardware level.